# How to limit CPU utilization for a process in ubuntu vm

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, memory-usage

I am using ubuntu 20.04 VM for a course. For an assignment, I need to run a command that creates some thread and two processes happen simultaneously. However as soon I run the command ubuntu slows down and the CPU utilization goes to 200% for that process. I allotted 8GB/16GB RAM to oracle VM and 6/12 CPUs (Oracle forbids to allocate beyond 6 CPUs).

A screenshot of situation is attached:[image]

Is there some way to prevent this to happening?? Maybe some alternative that takes less CPU but more time? Also will this issue occur in WSL2??

PS: I am new to ubuntu and don't know the inner working at all. My friends and the Teaching assistants are not familiar with VM. I cannot dual boot ubuntu, last time it gave serious issues.

Comment: last time it gave serious issues. Explain please.

Comment: The hard disk was not partitioning properly and the experience while using dual booted ubuntu was very bad, the graphics were not nice, it used to hang a lot and discharge at 3x and finally it vanished after a windows update

Comment: Clearly you need to understand (1) hardware and "drivers" requirements, namely graphics card/chip, and (2) how to manage a dual-boot, something that's easier then ever with UEFI and OSes installed in the proper UEFI mode.

Comment: That makes no sense the partitioning of the hard drive in no way affects the graphics. Any way it sounds like it was poorly installed not the Os s fault.